# Codeigniter replacing $_POST within a if statement

Tags: php, codeigniter

If I have an if statement currently using `$_POST` what would be the best way to do this using $this->input->post();?

**Example:**

```
if($_POST)
{
  Do This

}
```

Comment: you should use CI way  $this->input->post() in your if statement, like if($this->input->post('postedvalue')) { //do your stuff here }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs,

```
$this->input->post('value')
```

returns the value or false if it doesn't exist, so you should use this:

```
if ($this->input->post('value'))
{
    // 'value' can be safely used now, because we know it's there
}
```